# Syncing Jailbreaked Ipod Touch

Tags: itunes, ipod-touch, jailbreak

As the title says, I jailbreak-ed my iPod touch for about a week by myself and now I want to sync it to iTunes without unjailbreaking the iPod.

After I plug my iPod touch into the computer, I opened iTunes manually and nothing happened. I then looked for information on how to unjailbreak it. I found out that I need to press the sleep/power button and the home button, after the steps, on my iPod there's a picture saying to plug the iPod onto iTunes and I did so. Then I pressed for the iTunes to restore my iPod, and it said that an error happened.

Please, can anyone help me either to sync my iPod without unjailbreaking? But if there's no way, can anyone teach me how to jailbreak my iPod Touch safely?

Also, now my iPod screen is stuck on the image that tells me to connect to iTunes.

Comment: Jailbreaking does not stop iTunes syncing. The sync should work as normal - no need to unjailbreak. Please can you describe your problem more precisely. Jailbreaking should not have changed sync behaviour at all.

Comment: It sounds like your iPod is now in DFU mode.Try holding down sleep and home while connected to your PC/Mac.

Answer (score 3):

You can unjailbreak an iPod or any other iDevice by restoring the device from a previously unjailbroken backup or you can download the latest update from Apple for your device and install that. IF there is one.

Apple doesn't want people jailbreaking so all you have to do is update the IOS or restore to an old non-jailbroken copy and it will 'unjailbreak' it.

Comment: The OP does not want to unjailbreak, he wants to get his syncing working.

Answer (score 0):

You might try pressing the power and home buttons again and try to get it to boot back into iOS.  Then, try the restore process again.